# Android Timer o Service

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Hola con todos tengo una aplicación que trabaja con una base de datos, quiero ejecutar una consulta en la base como la que dejo mas adelante, el detalle es que este método(consulta) solo debe ejecutarse a las 7:30 de la mañana todos los días alguien me puede ayudar con este problema.

De ante mano gracias por la ayuda

```
public void borrarRegistros(){
    String consulta="delete from registros"; //borrar todos los registros de la tabla registros
    MainActivity.adapter.openSqliteDataBaseInDevice();
    try {
        Cursor c=MainActivity.adapter.get_sqliteDB().rawQuery(consulta,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        c.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){
    }
    MainActivity.adapter.closeSqliteDataBaseInDevice();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lo ideal para tu caso no es ninguna de las dos, por lo menos el servicio no directamente. Necesitas usar el [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), que te asegura de "despertar" tu aplicación, aún si esta no es ejecutándose, y mediante un [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), disparar la acción o consulta que necesitas! Más info aca "[Alarmas recurrentes](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)". El servicio de alarma puede despertar un servicio y hacer la consulta en segundo plano.

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, QueryService.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Poner alarma para comenzar a las 7:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() permite definir el intervalo de repetición
long unDia = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    unDia, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: disculpa @Tano si necesito ejecutar una tarea cada 10  minutos aunque la app se cierre como seria?

Comment: @even si necesitas cada dies minutos, tenés que calcular 10 minutos en milisegundos. 10 minutos --> 600 segunds --> 600000 milisegundos
`alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, <primera_ejecucion_en_ms>, 600000, <intent>)`